# chromatic number of $G(n, p)$, when $p =const$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, probabilistic-method

Let $G_{n,p}$ be the binomial random graph on $n$ vertices, i.e. a certain edge is within the graph with probability $p$.

what is the theorem related to this statement about chromatic number of Random Graphs?

"Asymptotically behavior of the chromatic number of $G(n, p)$, when $p =const$.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04836.pdf is potentially useful